# Readability for function composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to practice function composition using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs) but wondering if it's overkilled and needed some advice on this.

Given the object below

```js
const articles = [
  {
    title: 'Everything Sucks',
    url: 'http://do.wn/sucks.html',
    author: {
      name: 'Debbie Downer',
      email: 'debbie@do.wn'
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'If You Please',
    url: 'http://www.geocities.com/milq',
    author: {
      name: 'Caspar Milquetoast',
      email: 'hello@me.com'
    }
  }
];
```

Make a boolean function that says whether a given person wrote any of the articles.

Sample function invocation

```js
isAuthor('New Guy', articles) // should return false
isAuthor('Debbie Downer', articles) // should return true
```

**My Solution**

First I create a function to grab the author name as below

```js
const get = _.curry(function(x, obj) { return obj[x]; });

const names = _.map(_.compose(get('name'), get('author'))); // ['Debbie Downer', 'Caspar Milquetoast']
```

Now that I have a function `names` ready to be used, I will try to construct `isAuthor` function and below is two of my attempts

**Attempt 1: without composition**

```js
const isAuthor = function(name, articles) {
  return _.contains(name, names(articles))
};
```

**Attempt 2 with composition**

```js
const isAuthor = function(name, articles) {
  return _.compose(
    _.contains(name), names
  )(articles);
}
```

Both attempts works with correct results, this question is asking solely from functional programming perspective as I'm totally new to this domain and wondering which attempt is favourable than the other, and hopefully this question will not get closed as opinion based, I sincerely thinks that this is not opinion based but seeking industrial practice in FP world.

Also feel free to provide any alternatives than the two attempts I've made, thanks!

Comment: Looks like your `get` function is Ramda's `prop` function.

Comment: Functional programming is about functions doing a single thing without side effects regardless of the complexity of your function. So it doesn't matter if you use multiple abstractions. As long as your function has a sole purpose. Simplicity is encouraged in any paradigm, so if you can do the same things with the least amount of layers without losing readability, then you're solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramda has a set of functions to work with nested properties. In your case we could combine `pathEq` and `any`:

1. `pathEq` returns `true` if a property at given path is equal to given value.
2. `any` applies a predicate function to each element of a list until it is satisfied.

The `isAuthor` function takes a name first then returns a function that takes a list:

```
const {compose, any, pathEq} = R;

const isAuthor = compose(any, pathEq(['author', 'name']));

isAuthor('Debbie Downer')(articles);
//=> true

isAuthor('John Doe')(articles);
//=> false
```

But this isn't necessarily better than:

```
const {curry} = R;

const isAuthor = curry((x, xs) => xs.some(y => y?.author?.name === x));
                                  
isAuthor('Debbie Downer')(articles);
//=> true

isAuthor('John Doe')(articles);
//=> false
```

Comment: Very nice!  Much better than my point-free solution!

Answer (score 2):

Both of your solutions seem like an overkill at least in my opinion.

Without using any libraries, a solution could be as simple as this for example:

```
 const isAuthor = (name, articles) => articles.some((article) => article.author.name === name)
```

Functional programming is cool, but it doesn't mean you should make things unnecessarily complex.

From your proposals the first one seems a lot more readable than the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Think of Ramda as a tool that helps you write in a certain way, and not something that dictates how you write your code.  Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the founders) allows you to write in a more declarative fashion, using nice compositions and pipelines.  But that doesn't mean that you need to use it everywhere you could.

The simple vanilla JS answer from tuomokar is probably all you need, but Ramda does have tools that might make that seem more readable to some.

So we could write something like this:

```js
const isAuthor = (name) => (articles) => 
  includes (name) (map (path (['author', 'name'])) (articles))

const articles = [{title: 'Everything Sucks',url: 'http://do.wn/sucks.html', author: {name: 'Debbie Downer',email: 'debbie@do.wn'}}, {title: 'If You Please', url: 'http://www.geocities.com/milq', author: {name: 'Caspar Milquetoast', email: 'hello@me.com'}}]

console .log (isAuthor ('New Guy') (articles))
console .log (isAuthor ('Debbie Downer') (articles))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {includes, map, path} = R                                  </script>
```

Note that your `get` is built in to Ramda as `prop`, and that your `names` can be written as `map (path (['author', 'name']))`.

We could make this point-free, on our own, or using a tool like http://pointfree.io/.  It might look like this:

```
const isAuthor = compose ((o (__, map (path (['author', 'name'])))), contains)
```

But I find that far less readable than any of the other suggestions.  I wouldn't bother.